# Privacy Policy(ies). Does the cookie “collect” browser data or “request” browser data?

Tags: privacy, cookies

I'm working on legal portion of my site, Privacy Policy in particular. I've done the research and found that nearly all the answers to my question (below), is generalized.

Question: Do cookies "collect" data from user browsers, or do cookies "request" then receive data from user browsers?

This seems to be a very important distinction. Do I put into my privacy policy that my site "collects" data from my users or do I "request" data from my users.

My understanding of the core functionality is that cookies request data of user browser or browser activity. Users control how their browser will respond (or handle cookies) in their browser settings. If users have the ultimate control of handling "responses" to cookies is it proper for website privacy policies to state that they use cookies to collect browser data? Isn't it more accurate to state something like: "We use cookies to request data from your browser. Depending on you have your settings, your response to our request my impact your experience." Or something along those lines.

For years the way I understood the phrase "cookies collect browser data" is that we (websites) force code (the cookie), onto your browser that opens a siv for all your activity to flow back to us. But this isn't the case at all. Cookies actually make a "request" (i.e., asks) for the user's permission first, and depending on how the user has set up their browser settings, the cookie request is honored or denied.

I'm trying to stay away from the term "collect" as a general matter. I think it's improperly used and leaves the wrong impression on users.

Has anyone else thought about this? Am I missing something?

UPDATE: Thank you for all the good responses below. I've concluded that my Privacy Policy will NOT state "We use cookies to collect info...," but rather: "We use cookies to request info..." because the former implies no consent required, whereas the latter implies consent required, and IS the more accurate case.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic. But to be more helpful: cookies are no active element, i.e. they neither collect nor request data. Cookies are just a kind of small storage set by the server which the browser will send back for each visits to the the same site. It can be used by the site to identity that it is the last user as the last time. Any data collection is done independently from the cookie but can be associated with the cookie and thus with the one visiting the site. Thus, cookies help to to collect data but they don't collect any data themselves.

Comment: This is the same generalized answer I've been finding. What's the triggering mechanism? If a cookie is just storage how does the browser know what to do, i.e., "...which the browser will send back for each visit to the same site." ? Doesn't a cookie "tell" a browser what it needs?

Comment: A cookie consists of the host-portion, which is the address of the website, and the actual information it stores (user-ID, session-token, ...), plus some instructions for the browser.
The browser will send the information-part back to the server each time the user requests a page from the defined host.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's why I'm against mentioning cookies (or any technology) in a privacy policy. A privacy policy should mention the things that you collect and how you use them, it should not necessary mention the technologies that make it happen. Imagine what would happen if every technology that make a website work would need to be mentioned...

Comment: @StackNoFlow "to request info" is absolutely wrong. You're not asking anything and the only "permission" is whether cookies are blocked or not. Since cookies are needed for almost every site needing login, very few have cookies disabled. Also worth pointing out that "user didn't have cookies blocked" is not explicit consent mentioned in GDPR, if that's a thing to worry about.

Comment: You asked the question, but it seems like you have already made up your mind and are only looking for agreement/validation. Most of the answers explain that cookies don't request, collect, or "do" anything, they are storage containers.

Comment: To the moderators, I agree this may be off-topic, but it's the closest place I could find. It would be helpful when in these situations the moderators could suggest an Exchange site, at least for newbies. Rewording the question would still leave it off-topic.

Comment: @Xander, I can see that constructive criticism of the moderators is not tolerated. Very sad. I suppose you'll delete this, too.

Comment: @StackNoFlow It is tolerated.  As I mentioned in my edit comment, the meta information was appropriate for a new question on [Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com), just not appropriate as as edit to the question here on main.  Feel free to re-post it there.

Comment: I had a decent conversation going on here. Five moderators disapproved and shut down the discussion with no help or suggestions. Not my kind of forum. I'll be moving on.

Comment: @StackNoFlow This site explicitly isn't a forum, it's strictly Q&A, and a lot of conventions revolve around that, including having a separate "meta" site for discussing policy. The 5 users who voted to close this question are not explicitly moderators, just users who have participated and built up their automated "reputation" scores. Finally, don't mistake "off topic" for meaning "not interesting": it's an interesting topic, just not the topic those users believe this site is for; nor does it make sense to expect every topic to have a home, and everybody who uses the site to know that home.

Comment: First of all, I can’t stand how nice you are all being when I’m trying to be upset here! I’ll concede this question since I didn’t understand the rules, but my updated comment, that Xander removed (see edit), still stands in general. Steffan should have flagged this question as off-topic or answered it, but not both. His reputation is 32K which kinda gives the green light for others to follow his lead, both in answering and flagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data being "collected" or "requested" is not the cookies, nor is it likely to be stored directly in the cookies.

The data your privacy policy needs to talk about is data you have requested explicitly, like name and e-mail address; and data you have collected because browsers send it by default, like referrers, IP addresses, and user-agent identifiers.

The role of cookies is to *tie together* this information across multiple requests - to know that the same user who told you their name was Bob is now accessing the home page; or that the same user who was connecting from China yesterday now appears to be connecting from Russia. But it is not the cookie that has taught you that their name is Bob, nor that their IP address is allocated to China.

Your privacy policy should first and foremost talk about *the data you are collecting*. If it must talk about cookies, it should talk about them as a technology used to "connect", "tie together", or "associate your browsing with" that data.

Comment: There's been excellent information about cookies, here, that I did understand before. Thank you to everyone. If I had a do-over I would have framed my question a little differently, but this answer helps me the most. Thank you, @IMSOP

Comment: "We use cookies to associate your browser with our website." I like that!

Answer (score 17):

Cookies neither collect nor request data. Cookies are just boxes you can store information in the client side that may be later retrieved when the client enters the site after setting the cookie.

Comment: Yes, this is accurate, but it's not just a box that is open for everything and anything poor into. If the cookie doesn't actually "request" data from the client there must, at least, be a gatekeeper to restrict what enters the box (sent back to the server), so to speak. Login credentials, times, referrers, ect.

Comment: "Login credentials, times, referrers" per se has nothing to do with cookies. The application developer chooses what to store. It is very unusual to store referrers in cookies, but a developer can chose to store whatever.

Comment: @StackNoFlow One use of cookies for analytics is that you can set one with essentially random data, and then if you see the same random data again you know it's the same user. The cookie is neither requesting or collecting data, it's a tool being used to collect data. When I put a sticker in someone's hair saying "valuable customer" so I remember they're a valuable customer, is the sticker requesting data or collecting it?

Comment: @immibis, I understand. But, can you place the sticker without asking the customer first? I'm assuming a cookie is only created after it determines that the browser will allow it? i.e., not being blocked. Meaning the owner of the browser gave consent. It also means that the cookie (a term I'm using very broadly now), or the browser must be doing something actively to communicate permissions. Similar to hand shakes, although that's probably not an accurate analogy.

Comment: @StackNoFlow does the sticker ask the customer anything? No. It's you who are doing the asking.

Comment: @StackNoFlow Did your browser ask you about all the cookies security.stackexchange set? I have currently 26 cookies set by this site, you probably have the same amount. There's your answer. There's also no "gatekeeper" who decides what you can put into cookies.

Comment: and the reason cookies are on by default is because a lot of stuff breaks without them. Like, for example, you couldn't log into websites.

Comment: If I had a do-over I think I would have presented my concern differently. I have a site that doesn't collect any PII. I want to proudly represent that by listing the things my site doesn't require of users that most every other site do. One of the items in the list is "We don't use tracking cookies to monitor your browsing habits. This is where I got stuck, and why I'm here. My site obviously sets cookies, but users don't typically fully understand the different types and how they work. I narrowed it down to "Collect" vs "Request." I need to state only that we do not collect PII...

Comment: ...and not mention cookies.

Answer (score 14):

HTTP is a [stateless protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). From the server pespective, every connection is a new one. Does not matter if you never ever connected to that server, or it's the 100th image you download from it in the last second. Your connection and every single other connection are just the same, faceless anonymous unknown connection. To put an identifier on each one, the cookie was created.

Think of a cookie as being a badge. If you talk to a server without a badge, it will send you one: *I don't know you, so your badge is `ID:ABC123`*.

Every time your browser talk back to the server, it sends the badge together:
*"I am `ID:ABC123` and need `logo.jpg`"*

If the server have anything to add, it will write a new badge and send to your browser:
*"You logged in, and are a valuable user. You are `ID:ABC123,TYPE:1`"*

When you ask the next thing, the badge goes back:
*"I am `ID:ABC123,TYPE:1` and need `custom_logo2.bmp`"*

It's a passive variable. It does not collect anything, it is just arbitrary data the server uses to identify you. Log in to any service, delete the cookies, refresh the page and it will ask who are you. The cookie is what identifies your browser and session.

This is a simplistic example. Usually cookies are encrypted and don't really hold values, they usually only point to a record on the server side where the real values are stored. Otherwise anyone could put the `TYPE:1` on their cookies and be a very special guest on the example service.

What is the privacy thing about the cookies? They can track you around. If I have a service hosting images, and you link a image from my server on your page, my server will receive a request from your client. The request will have a special field named `Referer`, and this tells me you are coming from, say, `your-own-site.org`, and I send him a cookie identifying him (`ID:ABC999`). Not only this, but I put on my database a record telling *ABC999 acessed your-own-site.org*. Later your client requests another image, but coming from `slashdot.org`, and the request gives me the ID `ABC999`. From my server I know the client accessed your site and slashdot, so I can start building a picture of what kind of sites he access, and what is his profile. Does not look like much, but if you think about Google, Facebook, and almost every Content Delivery Network, they track almost every single site you access. That's why almost every browser have a *Block third party cookies* option somewhere: this way the client will only store and send cookies for the domain he is accessing, not every CDN, image storage, telemetry or analytics site around the world.

Comment: Very nice description! And useful..thank you! What I'm trying to determine is do websites "collect" or gain ANY information from a client without making some kind of request for that information? Whether it's passive or direct. In short, if I got this right, it sounds like no. Which means the user/client must authorize the data/info transfer, which is typically done by the user either implementing "Block third party cookies" or not. So, if a user/client is NOT blocking third party cookies then they are essentially authorizing data "collection", the transfer of data/info back to the server.

Comment: @StackNoFlow I highly doubt that your opinion of "by not turning off this obscure checkbox in their browser they authorized the data collection" will stand up to GDPR.

Comment: @immibis, I agree. I'm more interested/concerned about the proper, accurate language I'm using in my Privacy Policy. A lot of these responses are pulling me away from that, although I'm still trying to address them. It's also still interesting how cookies and browsers interact.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is just a piece of text. It doesn't "collect" or "request" anything, it isn't an active component, and so it all depends on how you use it.

It can be used to collect and store some data about the user, like language preferences for example. The cookie will contain something like `lang=es`, and that means the user should be shown the content in Spanish. Or it can be used to identify the user, so for example it could contain `id=482477359937882940034` and that can be used to serve content specifically to one user (like their email, private messages, etc.) or track them by linking several different requests to the same ID.

The server usually sets and modifies the cookie, and send it to the browser. The browser then sends it back to the server with every request. It's basically data that is continually passed back and forth.

So your privacy policy should say that "your website uses cookies to...", and then it depends what you use them for. I don't know what exactly you use them for, so I can't give you any specific advice, but I'm pretty sure that a sentence like "We use cookies to request info..." is very likely to make no sense at all. To be honest, nobody cares about cookies, and the cookie law (EU law, I'm assuming you are in the EU) was just a stupid law. The GDPR law (EU law) is a much more complete law, and focuses on personal data in general. What matters is what you do with those cookies, what data you collect, for what purpose, and if it's a legitimate purpose according to the GDPR. It's a pretty complex law, but I can only tell you that if you are trying to avoid asking for the user's explicit consent by assuming they can always tweak their browser settings, you are on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

Servers don't have to do anything. Client browsers send cookies to the servers together with the request willingly - because they expect it to be useful for the server to provide the client with some service based on the cookie they store, so to speak.

I am not sure what either of those two (collect vs request) in this context mean but the server is in a passive relationship with client browser here. You can as well disable storage (and sending) of cookies in your browser if that's what you wish.

Comment: Just because cookies are under full control of the web browser doesn't mean the OP can assume every user knows that.

Comment: Ignorantia non excusat. Judging from the title it seems like OP wants to put blame on servers for using cookies.

Comment: "Servers don't have to do anything" - that is just plain wrong. The *server* has to set the cookie, otherwise there would be nothing for the browser to send back.

Comment: Server doesn't set anything, server sends back to the client the cookie and the client can and doesn't have to save it and send it during future requests.

Answer (score -1):

The cookie STORES data, the server will collect/store data within it, and 'request' data back out of it later.