# Where will cookie be created. Client side ? Server side ? How it will be validated

Tags: session-management

I wanted to know where exactly a cookie be generated ie., client side / server side.Because if I intercept the request before logging into the application, Header with cookie will be displayed . So, Is it generated at client side ?

Please let me know.Thanks!

Comment: you can set them before a request or a response. your situation sounds like a server created a cookie that the browser persisted and sends in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 4):

A cookie can be generated both on the server side and on the client side. On the client side a cookie can be generated with Javascript and is typically used to persist user interface settings (like language, color scheme, number of items to display...) between different URL's or repeated visits of the same server. Cookies for session management which are associated with a user are instead created on the server side.

How cookies gets validated (and if at all) depends on the purpose of the cookie. But session cookies gets validated at the server since they are typically used as a kind of authentication credential. Validation of session cookies might be done in multiple ways depending on the structure of the cookie, i.e. it might be a database lookup or it might be decryption (and integrity check) of the cookie etc.

Answer (score 2):

Creation behavior depends entirely on the application. Some will encrypt and sign the cookie, making client-side cookies invalid and useless. Others accept whatever you set, and use it.

Usually, cookies are generated server-side. It is used for the application running on server to differentiate the connections, because HTTP is a stateless protocol. If you connect without sending any cookie, the server will generate one and give you. Your browser will use that cookie afterwards. [On this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187984/privacy-policyies-does-the-cookie-collect-browser-data-or-request-browser/187990#187990) I explain cookies with more details.

Some applications allow for cookie creation client-side. When the application receives an unknown cookie, it just assumes the cookie as valid. Some PHP applications, for example, allows you to set `PHPSESSID` client-side before connecting, and will create a new session with the given ID.

Validation depends entirely on the application too. Security-conscious developers that know to never ever blindly trust anything that comes from the client will encrypt and sign them, other developers will accept them as they are. In some bizarre cases, you just create a cookie `isAdmin=1` and access the service as admin.